# Structure Products & Categories - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am creating a product catalogue database with 10000s of products and wondered whats the best way to structure them in a NoSQL database?

I need to make sure that i can create a category structure to build the menu on the fly (which will be cached daily)

First I thought that the products could contain their own category data

- EAN is the Primary Key
- CatSlug is the Sort Key

Product json

```
Products: [

 {
    "EAN" : {"S" : "123456"}, 
    "CatSlug" : {"S" : "drill"}, 
    "CatParent" : {"S" : "drill"}, 
    "Name" : {"S" : "Drill"}, 
    "Img" : {"S" : "/img/img.png"},
    "Desc" : {"S" : "Description"}
    ....

 },
 {NEXT PRODUCT}

]
```

But doing this would be difficult to create a menu structure.
Then I though having the CatSlug as the PK would be better to create the menu structure, but you would still need to go through loads of items to create this.

Having it as a separate table is quicker, but seems wrong for this type of database.

Is there a good way to do this in Dynamo DB?

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you’re trying to do. However, it sounds like you want some sort of aggregated or materialized view of some of the data in the products. You should take a look at this AWS blog post. It discusses (among other things) how to create and maintain a different/related view of your data in real time (which would save you from having to cache it daily). https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

You can express your category hierarchy in CatSlug using this pattern: cat#cat#cat...
then build a secondary global index with CatSlug as PK, and EAN as SK.